# Envio de email Cron Cpanel y Laravel

Tags: laravel, cron

Busco enviar desde laravel un email en cola con una tarea programada, localmente me funciona bien pero desde el servidor compartido no me está enviando el mail. Por favor agradezco mucho que alguien me pueda iluminar.

El cron en cpanel lo configure de la siguiente manera:

```
/usr/local/bin/ea-php72 /home/dtanco/sistema/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Es la primera vez que utilizo un cron y creo comprender que la ruta tiene que apuntar al archivo artisan que está home/dtanco/sistema/artisan

Si a la tarea programada le saco >> /dev/null 2>&1 me llega un mail con el  siguiente contenido:

**Running scheduled command: '/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/bin/php' 'artisan' envio:mail > '/dev/null' 2>&1**

Lo que me hace entender que se está ejecutando la tarea programada de laravel ya que me indica el nombre del comando **envio:mail**

El archivo de mi tarea programada en laravel realiza lo siguiente:

```
public function handle()
{
    //Trae el ultimo id insertado y verifica que el estado envio sea 0
    $ultimoMailInsertado = DescargaLibro::where('envio', 0)->latest('id')->first();
    Mail::to($ultimoMailInsertado->email)->send(new EnvioLibro);
}
```

Y la clase EnvioLibro:

```
public function build()
{
    $ultimoMailInsertado = DescargaLibro::where('envio', 0)->latest('id')->first();
    DescargaLibro::where('id', $ultimoMailInsertado->id)->update(['envio' => 1]);

    return $this->view('email.envio-libro')
            ->attach(public_path('pdf/libro.pdf'), [
                     'as' => 'libro.pdf',
                     'mime' => 'application/pdf',
                ]);

}
```

En modo local ejecuto el comando php artisan schedule:run o el comando php artisan envio:mail y ambos funcionan de forma correcta, entiendo que algo estoy haciendo mal en el cron de cpanel, pero ya hice millones de cosas y no me funciona. Agradezco mucho su tiempo y toda clase de sugerencia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucione, gracias a todos !!

Comment: pon la solucion aqui y di como lo has hecho. Gracias

Comment: Eso, explica la solución. Poner una respuesta que dice que lo solucionaste sin explicar cómo no sirve...

Comment: Ah disculpen...muchas gracias!! muchas estaría bien? saludos